# Pass variable into pthread_create function

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm building a multi-threaded network chat program, but I can't figure out how to pass variables into `pthread_create`.

I have the following line of code that creates a thread:

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, receive, (void *) socket_fd);
```

My receive function looks like this:

```
void * receive(void * socket) {
    int socket_fd, response;
    char message[MESSAGE_BUFFER];
    socket_fd = (int) socket;

    while(true) {
        response = recvfrom(socket_fd, message, MESSAGE_BUFFER, 0, NULL, NULL);
        if (response) {
            printf("\nServer> %s", message);
            printf("%s", prompt);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I pass a `prompt` variable into this `receive` function, when calling `receive` in `pthread_create`?

Comment: Do you just want to pass a pointer to a `struct`? Just see the example [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pack all of the data you want to pass to your thread on creation in a single struct and pass its pointer through the last parameter of `pthread_create`. in short:

define a struct:

```
typedef struct{
     char* prompt;
     int socket;
} thread_data;
```

and then call `pthread_create`:

```
thread_data data;
// place code here to fill in the struct members...
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, receive, (void *) &data);
```

in your receive function:

```
void * receive(void * threadData) {
    int socket_fd, response;
    char message[MESSAGE_BUFFER];

    thread_data* pData = (thread_data*)threadData;
    socket_fd = pData->socket;
    char* prompt = pData->prompt;

    while(true) {
        response = recvfrom(socket_fd, message, MESSAGE_BUFFER, 0, NULL, NULL);
        if (response) {
            printf("\nServer> %s", message);
            printf("%s", prompt);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But one must be careful with this if one passes (a pointer to) the same struct in more than one call to `pthread_create()`, and any of those threads or the parent thread also modifies the struct.  Proper synchronization is required in such a case.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. This is simply the most basic solution and it does not show any synchronization and locking mechanism that's required  in the case of a shared resource.